# joining 5 tables to obtain all comments made about goal where id = 2

Tags: sql, join

I need to return all comments that were made on a goal where id = 2

Tables:

```
goals.id = objectives.goal_id
objectives.id = steps.objective_id
steps.id = transactions.step_id
comments.id = transactions.comment_id
```

transactions table keeps track of all the steps a comment was related to.

Each comment can be related to multiple steps, therefore a table (transactions - I know, bad naming convention on this table) to keep track of each step and the comment.

So the transactions table is set up like this:

```
transactions.step_id | transactions.comment_id
```

So the user would like to view all comments that relate to goal where id = 2

I have never done anything over 2 tables, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: "transactions" makes me smile. In one of the first projects I worked on I thought "order" was a good table name.  Between you and me there are at least a few good table names left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select c.*
from goal g 
inner join objectives o on g.id = o.goal_id 
inner join steps s on o.id = s.objective_id 
inner join transaction t on s.id = t.step_id 
inner join comments c on t.comment_id = c.id
where g.id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what i was writing :)

One thing if the relations are no obligatory maybe need to use left join in some cases

Comment: +1, just helping get some points so you can start commenting. :-)